# Three.js multiple skeletal animations

Tags: animation, three.js

I have two skeletal animations: the first animation is based ( all body. For example, the walk), the second - only arms. How can i join keyframes from the second animation to based, when it is working? I think, that recalculate based animation, when it is working, was solved my issue, but it fail.  How can i make the similar things?

Comment: This may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570689/ also https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5516

Answer (score 0):

Combine them like in this example about animation blending? http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_skinning_blending

I think at least when the animations don't affect the same vertices you can play them together like that and they don't interfere.