# Three.js skeletal animations not working unless source is modified

Tags: animation, three.js

Using Three.js r68+ I have been needing to very slightly modify the source to get my animations working correctly. Unmodified only one of each type of model are animated (there are multiple spawns of each type of model).

This is the modified source at line 29407 (posted code beginning at 29389):

```
THREE.AnimationHandler = {

LINEAR: 0,
CATMULLROM: 1,
CATMULLROM_FORWARD: 2,

//

add: function () { console.warn( 'THREE.AnimationHandler.add() has been deprecated.' ); },
get: function () { console.warn( 'THREE.AnimationHandler.get() has been deprecated.' ); },
remove: function () { console.warn( 'THREE.AnimationHandler.remove() has been deprecated.' ); },

//

animations: [],

init: function ( data ) {

    // original -> if ( data.initialized === true ) return;
    if ( data.initialized === true ) return data; //<-- modified
```

The function now returns the animation data if initialized. I'm assuming it doesn't do so because of caching. My question is what is the best practice for animating multiple models that have the same animation names? I tried naming them uniquely per model name ie: "Death_MaleWarrior" but this had no effect.

Currently my models and animations are handled like so:

```
var modelArray = [];
var geoCache   = [];
var loader     = new THREE.JSONLoader(true);

var _MODEL = function(data){

  this.data       = data;  
  this.mesh       = null;
  this.animations = {};
  this.canAnimate = false;

  this.parseAnimations = function () {

    var len,i,anim;

    if (this.mesh) {

          if( this.mesh.geometry.animations ){
              this.canAnimate = true;
              len = this.mesh.geometry.animations.length;
              if( len ){
                  for(i=0;i<len;i++){
                      anim = this.mesh.geometry.animations[i];
                      if( anim ){
                        this.animations[anim.name] = new THREE.Animation( this.mesh, anim );
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  };

  this.playAnimation = function(label){

    if (this.canAnimate) {
      if( this.animations[label] ){
        //if( this.animations[label].data ){
          this.animations[label].play(0,1);
        //}
      }
    }
    return false;

  };

  this.load = function(geo){

    var mat;

    mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:somecolor, skinning:true})

    this.mesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geo,mat);

    this.mesh.position.x = this.data.position[0];
    this.mesh.position.y = this.data.position[1];
    this.mesh.position.z = this.data.position[2];

    this.parseAnimations();

    scene.add(this.mesh);

    this.playAnimation('Idle');

  };

  this.init = function(){

    var geo;

    if( geoCache[this.data.name] ){
      geo = geoCache[this.data.name];
      this.load(geo); 
    }else{
       geo = loader.parse(JSON.parse(this.data.json)).geometry;
       geoCache[this.data.name] = geo;
       this.load(geo);            
    }        

  };

  this.init();

};

var dataArray = [{name:'MaleWarrior',json:'json_data',position:[x,y,z]},{name:'FemaleWarrior',json:'json_data',position:[x,y,z]},{name:'MaleWarrior',json:'json_data',position:[x,y,z]}];

for(var i=0, len=objectArray.length; i<len; i++){
  modelArray.push(new _MODEL(dataArray[i]) );
}
```

In this example the first MaleWarrior will animate but the second will not. If there was a second female she would not be animated either as the animation (even though it is a new THREE.Animation() ) will be considered initialized and will not return any data. If I do not check for the existence of animations.data in playAnimation I get the error ""Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined " on line 29665".

Is what I'm doing bypassing animation caching and hurting performance? I feel like I'm missing something. How will an animation play without data?

All animation names are the same for every model "Idle", "Run", "Attack" etc.

Any help would be appreciated. If I'm not being clear enough please let me know. I have added additional detail.

Comment: There is no necessity of modifying the code.
Perhaps you should check the way you are exporting your models if you are using the JSON loader? Also, for each THREE.SkinnedMesh you create and for which you want the animation to play, you must create a THREE.Animation object, and call its .play method. Perhaps you thought you had to create only one THREE.Animation for all THREE.SkinnedMesh?
Most likely you must check your JSON and its loading, since geometry.animations may not be loading. Otherwise, I see no reason your code shouldn't work. Perhaps also that Animationhandler modificated line.

Comment: Also, usually animation.data IS defined. It is set when you call THREE.Animation constructor. We could help you more if you posted links to the rest of your code and the JSON file you are loading.

Comment: Each skinned mesh gets in own array of THREE.Animation objects. The parseAnimations function is ran for each individual mesh. The AnimationHandler (pre r68) line is commented out. There is no issue with the JSONLoader. Everything worked fine pre r68.

Comment: Also, you are creating a global called "animation" in that code, since you forgot to specify local scope by using "var", should be "var animation = new THREE.Animation...".

Comment: I believe you have a larger object, that has those .animations and .mesh properties, it would be useful to see that, as your problem can be there, and not in this piece of code you quoted here.

Comment: I added var animation; No change.

Comment: One thing I would do, is to store the animations differently, I would to this:
"this.animations = {};"
then in that loop in parseAnimations,
"this.animations[anim.name] = new THREE.Animation(this.mesh, anim);"
and my .playAnimation would be simply "if(this.animations[label]) this.animations[label].play();", this is somewhat equivalent to what in C++ would be the usage of a "std::map<std::string, THREE.Animation>"

Comment: I added more code to the question. I'll try storing the animations differently like you suggested. Seems much cleaner.

Comment: dataArray has more than one typo, including a ":" instead of a "," , a "," inside quotes that should have been after the closing quote, and the lack of a "}" at the end.

Comment: The actual dataArray is an ajax loaded response. This is just an example, but fixed.

Comment: It would be very useful to actually see the JSON you are loading. This https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/loaders/JSONLoader.js#L464 could be an issue depending on the exporter perhaps.

Comment: The loader is definitely not the problem. The animation data from the json file is loading in just fine as it always has. Here is an example so you can see: http://www.titansoftime.com/webgl/so_demo.js

Comment: Here is the loader file itself: http://www.titansoftime.com/webgl/JSONLoader.60.js

Comment: Why are you using that old version of JSONLoader? three.min.js r69 already has THREE.JSONLoader. No reason to use a separate file, much less a separate file 9 versions old.

Comment: Fair enough, but it works. I'll update it eventually. The loader is not causing this animation problem. If it was no animations would work. Using unmodified src allows one of each mesh type to animate.

Comment: Using unmodified src allows as many meshes to animate as you want, separately, as it should be, at least on my own code. Since you are using modified three.js and old versions of files, it is hard to say where your problem is.

Comment: I now am using the JSONLoader built into the build (code example edited to reflect). No change. Same issue. The only edit to the Three.js build is the one you see in the original question.

Comment: Well, you haven't applied what I suggested, of storing animations in this.animations with a key that is their name string.

Comment: I just did, now I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined " on line 29682 of Three.js. There is no animation.data object because of "if ( data.initialized === true ) return;"

Comment: Update to your new code, then (that is the code you quoted in the question).

Comment: Do you mean changing "if ( data.initialized === true ) return;" to "if ( data.initialized === true ) return data;"? If I do that everything works fine.

Comment: No, I meant for you to make the code quoted in the question text to the "animations[anim.name] = new THREE.Animation(...)" blablabla.
I suggest you open an issue at mrdoob's three.js Git asking him about the possibility of changing that "return;" to "return data;" in the official three.js.

Comment: Ah yea I updated the code in the question. K, I'll open an issue there.

Comment: That code would now work if you changed some lines:
"
                       animation = new THREE.Animation( this.mesh, anim );
                        animation.loop = true;
                        this.animations[anim.name] = animation;"
to
"this.animations[anim.name] = new THREE.Animation( this.mesh, anim );"
You don't need to set .loop, it loops by default.

Comment: I edited the code, no effect =[

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an official three.js bug.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5516